# NLTK Naive Bayes rejecting everything

Tags: python, nltk

I am attempting to use the NLTK Naive Bayes classifier to guess which articles I will like on arXiv.org and indeed I got >85% accuracy from about 500 article titles.  Unfortunately, I realized it was just classifying all the articles as 'bad'

On the bright side, it gives me a list of informative features that sort of makes sense.
I have searched on this site https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nltk+naive+bayes and looked at [NLTK's book](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch06.html) as well as [another tutorial](http://streamhacker.com/2010/05/10/text-classification-sentiment-analysis-naive-bayes-classifier/) (both deal with movies reviews from NLTK's own files).

Is there anything glaringly wrong with how I train this classifier?  Hopefully the code snippet underneath is enough.  Is it possible rejecting all titles correct for Naive Bayes?

```
def title_words(doc, vocab):
    """ features for document classifier"""
    words = set([x.lower() for x in doc[0].replace(". ", " ").split(' ')])
    features = dict([( 'contains(%s)' % word , (word in words)) for word in vocab] )
    return features

def(classify)
# get articles from database
conn = sqlite3.connect('arxiv.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# each row in the database is a 3-tuple: (title, abstract, tag)
articles = c.execute("select * from arXiv").fetchall()

# build vocabulary list
for the in articles:
        vocab = vocab | set([x.lower() for x in the[0].split(' ')])
# get feature dictionary from title
titles = [(title_words(x, vocab),x[2])  for x in articles]

n = len(titles)/2
train_set, test_set = titles[:n], titles[n:]
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)

print nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set)
classifier.show_most_informative_features(20)

conn.close()
```

---

is there a problem if the number of features is around 2000?  common words like "the" and "because" are unlikely distinguish between "interesting" and "boring".  I imagine instead I am looking for specialized terms in different combinations, so I was hoping the classifier would pick out which specialized terms would induce me to read...

Comment: Have you tried the MaxentClassifier? Sometimes NaiveBayes just isn't very good.

Comment: Looks like you're using only single-word features? Perhaps there just isn't a linear boundary between "interesting" and "not interesting". Try bigram features.