# NLTK classifier precision and recall are always none (0)

Tags: python, nltk

I have used Python `NLTK library` and the Naive Bayes classifier to detect if a string should be tagged "php" or not, based on training data (Stackoverflow questions in fact).

**The classifier seem to find interesting features**:

```
Most Informative Features
     contains-word-isset = True             True : False  =    125.6 : 1.0
      contains-word-echo = True             True : False  =     28.1 : 1.0
       contains-word-php = True             True : False  =     17.1 : 1.0
     contains-word-this- = True             True : False  =     16.0 : 1.0
     contains-word-mysql = True             True : False  =     14.3 : 1.0
      contains-word-_get = True             True : False  =     11.7 : 1.0
   contains-word-foreach = True             True : False  =      7.6 : 1.0
```

Features are defined as follows:

```
def features(question):
    features = {}
    for token in detectorTokens:
        featureName = "contains-word-"+token
        features[featureName] = (token in question)
    return features
```

**but** it seems the classifier decided to never tag a string as being a "php" question.
**Even a simple string like: "is this a php question?" is being classified as False.**

Can anyone help me understand this phenomenon?

Here is some partial code (I have 3 or 4 pages of code, so this is just a small part):

```
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
cross_valid_accuracy = nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, cross_valid_set)

refsets = collections.defaultdict(set)
testsets = collections.defaultdict(set)

for i, (feats, label) in enumerate(cross_valid_set):
    refsets[label].add(i)
    observed = classifier.classify(feats)
    testsets[observed].add(i)

print 'Precision:', nltk.metrics.precision(refsets['pos'], testsets['pos'])
print 'Recall:', nltk.metrics.recall(refsets['pos'], testsets['pos'])
```

Comment: I found a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804588/nltk-naive-bayes-rejecting-everything?rq=1

Comment: I guess it's worth to provide sample labeled dataset with your issue. The only guess i have is that it's small and there is only one php question, one with `php` within.

Comment: @alko I'll try to provide labeled dataset (will take some time). By the way the training set was 5000 questions and test set another 5000 questions. But even if there was only one 'php' question in the training set, the classifier found that there is a 17:1 chance that the word 'php' is good to classify it as 'php'. Why is he not classifying accordingly?